# CorruptSSTableException as value length exceeds the maximum of 268435456, which is set via max_value_size_in_mb in cassandra.yaml

Tags: cassandra, datastax, corrupt-data

What does this mean in Cassandra ? does it mean a value in a column has exceeded.If so how do we find out which value has caused this exception. 
We are using 3.7 version of Cassandra . Also how to ensure that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace. You may need to run scrub.